# TryValidateProperty not work with generic function

Tags: c#, data-annotations, validation

UPDATED:
when i executing Unit Test project and then it will return **Was unhandled** This test result also contained an inner exception **instead of** "Assert.IsTrue failed. The Description field is required." Result like (0 Pass, 1 FAIL, 1 Total) but we are not getting any exception at all if i debug with F11

```
    [TestMethod]
    [Asynchronous]
    [Description("Determines whether the selected or single property is valide using the validation context or validate single properties.")]
    public void ValidateSigleWithDataAnnotation()
    {
        LookupsServices lookupsservices = new LookupsServices();
        Lookups lookups = new Lookups() { Description = "", LookupReference = 2, DisplayOrder = 50};
        lookupsservices.Lookups.Add(lookups);

        //THIS IS NOT WORKING
        string message = ValidateProperties.ValidateSingle(lookups, "Description");
        Assert.IsTrue(message.Equals(""), message);
        //THIS IS WORKING
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateProperty(lookups.Description , new ValidationContext(lookups, null, null) { MemberName = "Description" }, results);
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Count == 0, results[0].ToString());
    }
```

Following is the Generic function to validate individual property

```
    public static string ValidateSingle<T>(T t, string PeropertyName) where T : class
    {
        string errorMessage = "";
        var ValidationMessages = new List<ValidationResult>();
        bool ValidationResult = Validator.TryValidateProperty(typeof(T).GetProperty(PeropertyName).Name,  new ValidationContext(t, null, null) { MemberName =  PeropertyName} , ValidationMessages);

        if (!ValidationResult) errorMessage += string.Format("\n{0}", ValidationMessages[0]);
        return errorMessage;
    }
```

Following is the Model where Description field id Required

```
public class Lookups
{
    public Lookups() { }
    [Key]
    public virtual int LookupReference { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting error "The Description field is required" if i am validating without Generic method, but why am not getting same error using Generic method?

Please Help me.....

Comment: "not working" is a very woolly description. Please say what you expected to happen, and what *did* happen.

Comment: Please edit that information into the question, rather than it being in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and as per per yours i updated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compare these two calls:

```
// In the generic method
Validator.TryValidateProperty(
    typeof(T).GetProperty(PeropertyName).Name, 
    new ValidationContext(t, null, null) { MemberName =  PeropertyName},
    ValidationMessages);

// The working call
Validator.TryValidateProperty(
    lookups.Description,
    new ValidationContext(lookups, null, null) { MemberName = "Description" },
    results);
```

In the first form, you're passing in the *name of the property*, i.e. "Description". In the second form, you're passing in the *value* of the property, i.e. "". To make the first call look like the second, you'd need:

```
typeof(T).GetProperty(PeropertyName).GetValue(t, null),
```

It's not entirely clear to me whether that's what you want (I haven't used `Validator` myself) but it *may* be the answer.